# SpriteKit Scrolling SKCameraNode Very Glitchy

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

When I scroll through on this scene with my code, it is extremely glitchy looking. Everything kind of jumps around very quickly until you let go. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
var lastTouch: CGPoint!
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first!
    lastTouch = touch.locationInNode(self)
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first!
    let touchLocation : CGPoint = touch .locationInNode(self)
    self.camera!.position = CGPointMake(self.camera!.position.x + (lastTouch!.x - touchLocation.x), self.camera!.position.y + (lastTouch!.y - touchLocation.y))
    lastTouch = touchLocation;
}
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first!
    let touchLocation : CGPoint = touch .locationInNode(self)
    self.camera!.position = CGPointMake(self.camera!.position.x + (lastTouch!.x - touchLocation.x), self.camera!.position.y + (lastTouch!.y - touchLocation.y))
    print(touches.count)
    lastTouch = touchLocation;
}
```

I can upload a gif/video if really necessary. Is this just a bug with SKCameraNode as it is so new? If anyone knows what I am doing wrong I'd love to hear. Thanks!

EDIT: [Click here to see a video of the issue](https://vid.me/glEZ)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, as it was a very simple mistake. As the camera node moved, the location in which you are touching would also move. I created a node that moves with the camera and get the touch's location in that node.